# can't install package gstat in R version 3.1.2

Tags: r, installation, gstat

I am trying to install the `gstat` package on the latest version of R (3.1.2) on windows. It is unsuccessful, even when trying to change the 64-bit version to the 32-bit version. Here is the message I get:

when installing the package, it says `"package "gstat" successfully unpacked  and MD5 sums checked"`

when loading the library `library(gstat)`, it says: `"stat is not available for r version 3.1.2"`...

could you help me solve this problem please?

Thank you,

aphili01

Comment: Are you certain? There is no package "stat" .  The R-forge page (see the info for `gstat` at CRAN) suggests the current build has failed.  You may need to contact the maintainer/developer directly.

Comment: CRAN also suggests that the windows binaries are fine. Did you solve the problem in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

First go to Tools > Check for package updates
and then sellect update all.

Now you can call the "gstat" package using library()